# Conda Enviroments are not Showing up in JupyterLab [WEB] Kernel Selection

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

On my development VM (CentOS) I switched from base python and JupyterLab (web version) to miniconda and JupyterLab (web version). Now I'm struggling to be able to switch to different environments.

0. I Installed miniconda
1. I uninstalled the original Jupyter installation with:

`/usr/bin/python36 -m pip uninstall -y jupyter jupyter_core jupyter-client jupyter-console jupyterlab_pygments qtconsole notebook nbconvert nbformat nbclassic nbclient jupyterlab-widgets jupyter-events jupyter-server jupyter-server-terminals`

2. Purged ~/.jupyter/
3. Installed jupyter on miniconda with: `conda install -c conda-forge notebook`
4. Installed nb_conda_kernels to manage conda environments from jupyter with:`conda install -c conda-forge nb_conda_kernels`
5. Created a test env with 'conda create --name test_1'

This environment shows up with `conda env list` but even after restarting JupyterLab, the only two options I have in the Kernel selector are:

- `Python 3 (ipykernel)`
- `python [conda env:root]*`

no `test_1` environment

also when I start JupyterLab I see alot of "ghosts" from the old installation like:

```
[W 2023-08-07 14:53:10.272 ServerApp] jupytext | error adding extension (enabled: True): The module 'jupytext' could not be found (No module named 'jupytext'). Are you sure the extension is installed?
```

So I clearly missed something in the uninstallation process.